# How to set utf-8 character into redis using redis-cli?

Tags: utf-8, redis

I want to set a utf-8 character "\u042e" into redis using redis-cli.

I tried:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set test "\u042e"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get test
"u042e"
```

Then I tried:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set test '\u042e'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get test
"\\u042e"
```

and

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set test `\u042e`
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get test
"`\\u042e`"
```

But what I want is (which I set from golang):

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get test
"\u042e"
```

Even I add --raw, that does not work.

Finally I tried:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set test Ю
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get test
"\xd0\xae"
```

It seems they are same bytes, but I am not totally sure.

Could I set a utf-8 charater into redis directly using redis-cli?

Comment: Just to be explicit, `\xd0\xae` *is* the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character [U+042E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/42e/index.htm)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `redis-cli` formats the output of commands by default - in your case it prints the bytes that encode the UTF-8 characters escaped, in the form of '\xNN'.

You can override this behavior and have the cli print the raw output with the '--raw' switch, like so:

```
$ redis-cli --raw
127.0.0.1:6379> SET test Ю
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> GET test
Ю
```